# Check if the column has single value that is repeating itself

Tags: sql, database

I'm working on a script to identify the column values that have

1. single value with repeating itself and there is no other value in that column.

For example,

```
00,
111,
2222,
33333,
444444,
5555555,
66666666,
777777777,
8888888888,
99999999999,
00000000000,
9999999999,
88888888,
7777777
```

Any value that is repeating it multiple times and has no other digit in that column; seeking help for a generic function or logic to test the same.

We can ignore any other values such as: **123****123****123** or 1**2**34543**2**1

Thanks.

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: Database is:  MySql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where replace(col, left(col, 1), '') = '';
```

This replaces the first character.  If nothing is left, then all values are the same.

Note:  Most databases support `replace()` and `left()`.  Those that do not have equivalent functionality with different function names.

Comment: Very clever take on this.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - This is returning the expected results but it seems very time taking. For fetching 200 records, it took 4mins. I have accepted the answer. Please if you could suggest a way to speed it up.

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta . . . You are going to have to scan the table -- and that would be causing the performance issue.  How large is the table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Table size is 129GB. It is joining with other tables though. I have been able to run the entire query by joining 5 tables and have retrieved the records in 60 mins.

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta . . . The time issue is probably due to all the other operations.  If this is one column in a source table, you might be able to filter before doing everything else.